# IIS 7 worker process

Tags: iis-7

I have iis 7.0 which each app pool running one website. however, some worker processes hve username: network service which i have no idea what apps they are running.

Is it possible to find them out ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at each website / application in IIS Manager and check what application pool they are using.

Foreach web site and applicaiton:
Select the site / application in IIS manager and select "Basic Settings". The name of the AppPool should be in the properties dialog that is displayed.

Would that be good enough?

Comment: network service is not a name of app pool, it's is a built-in windows identity. I just want to know what software/app running using that identity. Maybe not a website but something else though it's using w3wp.exe.

Comment: Well, then you start in the "Application Pools" list which is the first child node in the website tree of the IIS Manager. In the application pools list you can see the Identity of each application pool. Since you have websites which are run under NetworkService account, at least one of them should have NetworkService as Identity. Then you match the name of the application pools with the web sites in the manner I described above to get all sites which use the NetworkService identity.